# Gridview button filed dynamically add

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having one DataGrid..I want to create one button field inside the DataGrid dynamically.

Button filed type is link type.. this button field is fill after checking some conditions in my database..any body help me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Jquery to add some controls or you can use httpwriter

[httpwriter msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpwriter.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this may require you do a tiny bit of reading/understanding.

Basically you do two things:
1) [Add the button design-time](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webforms/controls/addingbuttonfieldstogridview.aspx) and 2) [choose its visibility based on database condition](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-and-responding-to-buttons-to-a-gridview-vb).